# What did I do wrong here? [Javascript Regex]

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am writing a registration form and I need the display name to be only numbers, letters and underscores.

Have a look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<form method="post" action="/" onsubmit="return check_form()">
    <input type="text" id="display-name" name="display-name" maxlength="255" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var name_regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_])+/

    function check_form()
    {
        if (!name_regex.test(document.forms[0].elements[0].value))
        {
            document.forms[0].elements[0].focus()
            alert("Your display name may only contain letters, numbers and underscores")
            return false
        }
    }
-->
</script>
```

It's obviously been trimmed down to not include anything not related to the problem but even this snippet doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your regex

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_])+/
```

Looks for

1. Start of string(check), followed by
2. 1 or more letters, numbers, or underscore (check)

And then whatever comes after it doesn't matter. This regex will match anything at all so long as it begins with a letter, number, or underscore

If you put a `$` at the end, then it will work - `$` matches 'end of string', so the only way it can match is if there are *only* numbers, letters, and underscores between the start and end of the string.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9_])+$/
```

Secondly, I'd suggest using `document.getElementById('display-name').value` instead of `document.forms` as it won't break if you rearrange the HTML, and is more 'the commonly accepted standard of what to do'

Comment: \w is a shorthand for letter, digits and underscores. I would simplify it to /^\w+$/

Comment: @Juan, in most lanugages, what counts as a word characters is system and locale dependant, is this not the case in JS?

Comment: Most RegEx references list \w as simply a shortcut to [a-zA-Z_0-9] . Java's: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern . PHP uses POSIX which basically says the same thing. Applies to JS too. `/\w/.test("é")` returns false when my locale is set to pt-br. I have never heard of \w being really smart about detecting other locales.

Answer (score 6):

My regexp would go along the lines of: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/`

edit: I think it's the lack of a line end `$` that makes it fail.

Answer (score 0):

By 'not working' I take it you mean it is letting invalid entries through (rather than not letting valid entries through).

As @Annan has said, this would probably be due to the lack of the `$` character at the end of the expression, as currently it only requires a single valid character at the start of the value, and the rest can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

What does "doesn't work" mean? Does it reject valid display names? Does it accept invalid display names? Which ones?

Per @Annan, leaving off the `$` would make the regexp accept invalid display names like `abc123!@#`.

If the code is rejecting valid display names, it may be because the parentheses are being matched literally instead of denoting a group (I'm not sure of the quoting convention in JS).

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script and meddled with the javascript. This seem to work:

```
<form method="post" action="/" onsubmit="return check_form()">
    <input type="text" id="display-name" name="display-name" maxlength="255" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var name_regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_])+$/;

    function check_form()
    {
        if (!name_regex.test(document.forms[0].elements[0].value))
        {
            document.forms[0].elements[0].focus();
            alert("Your display name may only contain letters, numbers and underscores");
            return false;
        }
    }
    -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys I should have been more specific.  Whenever I added spaces the values were still being accepted.  The dollar sign `$` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to write it still would be

```
var name_regex = /^([a-z0-9_])+$/i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler:

```
var name_regex = /^\w+$/;
```